# MS WORD: how to use the page number in footer and use it in the text

Tags: ms-word, footer, page-numbering

I have a Word document, with the page number appearing in the footer.
And in the document I have a text saying something like this:

`This document have X pages`

Is there anyway to get the number in the document footer and automatically update the information in the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your cursor where you want to have the page count appearing then follow these steps:

1. Place your cursor where you want to have the page count to appear
2. `Ctrl + F9` -> Curly brackets will appear
3. Type `NUMPAGES` within the curly brackets
4. While the cursor is still within the curly brackets hit `F9`

Finished!

Assuming you have Microsoft Word 2007 or higher you can also do the same with these steps:

1. Place your cursor where you want to have the page count to appear
2. `Insert` -> `Quick Parts` -> `Field...`
3. Select `NumPages` on the left side
4. Click `OK`

Both ways provide you the exact same result.

You just inserted a so called `Field` in Microsoft Word representing the total page count of your document. It will automatically update once you print preview the document or when you place the cursor over the field and hit `F9`.

You can use many different fields for different purposes.

---

**Update**

According to your comment you want to have the total number of pages minus the first page. Microsoft describes how you can calculate the total number in such a case in their support article [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-NumPages-field-536fa716-025b-4dd6-8a04-8a190b5b1490?CorrelationId=9bb45d67-4772-47e6-9129-a366addbc414&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102017464).

Therefore use there steps:

1. Place your cursor where you want to have the page count to appear
2. `Ctrl + F9` -> Curly brackets will appear
3. Enter `=`
4. Again press `Ctrl + F9` -> another curly brackets will appear within the first ones
5. Type `NUMPAGES` within the second pair curly brackets
6. Enter `- 1` after the second curly brackets but still within the first ones. Now it should look like this `{={NUMPAGES} - 1}`
7. While the cursor is still within the curly brackets hit `F9`

In case you have more then one front page just increase the number to subtract.

Comment: That works fine, But i was not I intended. That presents the document total pages, what i want is the last page number of the document. An exemple:I have a document with the total of 10 pages. but the first page is the cover so it doesn't count to the document page number in the footer. even though the document have a total of 10 pages, the last page is the ninth...

Comment: Ok, I got it. See my updated answer. Now I realized that your question is actually a duplicate from: https://superuser.com/a/431779/373321